# Google one-tap log in with Auth0

Tags: reactjs, ember.js, auth0

We currently user AuthO as a platform to allow for google login and sign up on our site, but I want to start using the google one tap login https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview

Is there a way for us to be able to set up the one tap log in while continuing to use Auth0 as a platform?

The idea is to not have an external connection into google's identity and login/sign up features outside of our standard infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this looking for the same answer, according to this link it is possible.

Steps:

1. Login with Google
2. Get the users mail
3. do another login via auth0 using the google connection (of the same social connection as configured for one-tap)
4. it will re-use the session

See:
https://community.auth0.com/t/integrating-google-one-tap-sign-up-login-with-auth0/20209/9